# How to write directly to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I want to write some text into a `JTextArea`. I think the answer is to extend `java.io.Writer`, but I'd like an authoritative answer here; is that the right thing to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with a writer? Do realize that the textarea needs to get told to repaint. That's what the own settext does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use `JTextArea.setText(String)` and `JTextArea.append(String)` to do this.

Comment: @Joe Sun/Oracle has very nice tutorials for swiny components: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html